# AWS and Gunicorn problem when reducing the backlog size

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, gunicorn, amazon-ecs

I have a cluster on AWS ECS (Fargate) to host my API. The API is built in Flask and I use Gunicorn to host my app. Now, since the default setting for Gunicorn backlog is 2048, i didn't want to keep so much requests waiting. I have tried reducing the backlog to 512, even 256, but i see no changes. The response time is pretty much the same and there are no error responses. I used Jmeter to simulate many concurrent users so that they can fill the backlog. How is this possible? Does Application Load Balancer on AWS have its' own backlog or queue to keep requests, so changing the Gunicorn backlog makes no difference?

Can someone explain to me why this is happening and what should I consider?